# How to prevent shifting of icons in a sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made an Icon Sidebar which consists of different icons that get bigger on mousehover. If i hover over the top icons every other icon that is below the one i hovered over, shifts downwards. So my question is how do i prevent the shifting of the icons. Thank you.

```
<div id="icon-bar" class="visible">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
    <span class="description">Home</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>
    <span class="description">Games</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-images"></i>
    <span class="description">Gallery</span></a>                            
</div>

<style>
#icon-bar {
width:100px;
height:100%;
background-color:blue;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
box-shadow:5px -10px 10px -2px #111;
}

#icon-bar a {
display:block;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
color:white;
font-size:47px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#icon-bar a:hover {
background-color: #CF0B61;
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.description{
display:none;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
}

#icon-bar a:hover .description {
display:block;
}

</style>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/az0om9dr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the icons with `absolute` in order to take them out of the document flow:

```css
#icon-bar {
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  box-shadow:5px -10px 10px -2px #111;
}

#icon-bar a {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
  color:white;
  font-size:47px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
  #icon-bar a:first-child {
    top:0;
  }
  #icon-bar a:nth-child(2) {
    top:94px;
  }
  #icon-bar a:nth-child(3) {
    top:188px;
  }

#icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #CF0B61;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.description{
  display:none;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:center;
}

#icon-bar a:hover .description {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="icon-bar" class="visible">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="description">Home</span></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i><span class="description">Games</span></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-images"></i><span class="description">Gallery</span></a>       
</div>
```

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/az0om9dr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Give fixed height to your a tag in icon-bar

```
#icon-bar a {
   display:block;
   text-align:center;
   padding:20px;
   color:white;
   font-size:47px;
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 }
```